# Atom php beatify

Tags: php, atom-editor

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Atom で のphpの整列をしようとすると

```
Could not find 'php-cs-fixer'. The program may not be installed.
```

と出て来ます。xampp と php は Cドライブに入ってます、
また 必要と言われた php-cs-fixer.phar もphpにかるので
Cドライブ ▶︎ xampp ▶︎ php ▶︎ php -cs-fixer.phar
のパスになっています。

どうすれば解決できますか。

Comment: スタック・オーバーフローへようこそ！　こちらのご質問ですが、回答者が問題を再現できるように、OS (Windows 10?) や Atom のバージョン、atom-beautify のバージョンなどの環境情報を追記して頂けませんでしょうか。質問文下の「編集」から自由に追記ができます。

Comment: エラーメッセージには https://github.com/Glavin001/atom-beautify#beautifiers を参考にインストール方法を確認しろ、と書かれています。どのようにインストールなさったのかも追記頂けると回答しやすいです。また同様に、コマンドプロンプトで `where.exe php-cs-fixer` を実行した結果も追記して頂きたいです。

Comment: 現在はエラーは消えましたが動いていないという状態です。 php-cs-fixer  は https://github.com/FriendsOfPHP/PHP-CS-Fixer#installation ここからダウンロードしました。

Comment: 以下手順です。手順①
ダウンロードすると
php-cs-fixer-v2.phar
なので、
php-cs-fixer.phar にリネーム

手順②
そのファイルを
c:\xampp\php\php-cs-fixer.phar
に置く

手順③
Atom エディタに行き

Settings▶︎Excuatble▶︎PHP▶︎
c:\xampp\php\

Comment: excuatble▶︎PHP-CS-Fixer には c:\xampp\php\php-cs-fixer としています

Comment: すいません、コメントは後からこの質問を見に来た人からは読みにくいので、質問文に直接追記頂けませんでしょうか？　質問文下の「編集」から自由に追記できます :)